# Angular 8/9 Keeps calling subscribe for json in a loop

Tags: angular, angular8

I only want to get the result from this json call once.
But in the console window I can see it is getting called in a loop.

**the component:**

```
 constructor(private dataService: DataService) {


    this.dataService.getData()
      .subscribe((data) => {
        console.log("DATA" + data); // keeps going forever
        this.info = data;

      });

  }
```

**the service**

```
    getData(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get("https://example.com/info")

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

That code should work as intended, since the `Observable` from `http.get` should only emit one result. You can always pipe through a `take(1)` operator to guarantee only one result is observed:

```js
this.dataService.getData()
  .pipe(take(1))
  .subscribe((data) => {
    console.log("DATA" + data); // keeps going forever
    this.info = data;
  });
```

However I think it more likely that the constructor of your component is being called multiple times and what is actually happening is you are making multiple http requests?

Answer (score 0):

use the OnInit method instead of the constructor.

Maybe you call the component several times, check that.